# How to build dynamic query argument for external query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to build dynamic query parameter based on declared variable for `EXTERNAL_QUERY`.
So I declare `STRING` variable via concatenation 2 strings:

```
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT "SELECT * FROM public.stats WHERE import_date >= "||"'2021-11-29'";
```

Then trying to set this variable as argument into `EXTERNAL_QUERY`:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY("dataset.location.conn_name", str);
```

It's returns an error:

```
Query error: Invalid table-valued function EXTERNAL_QUERY Connection argument in EXTERNAL_QUERY must be a literal string or query parameter
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: It seems to be related with this EXTERNAL_QUERY... What is this ?  What means "connection argument" in it?

Comment: it is a `str` variable

Comment: Unfortunately this is not allowed at the moment, there is FR for this in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161764387). I suggest to show your interest there to increase the priority of the case.

Comment: It's possible using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not perfect, but works for me.

```
    DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT '''"SELECT * FROM public.stats WHERE import_date >= "'''||"'2021-11-29'";
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE """
    SELECT * FROM EXTERNAL_QUERY(\"dataset.location.conn_name\",?);
    """
    USING str
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get this to work. Keep getting this error: `Query error: Unexpected TVF argument type found, expecting literal, query parameter, or variable of type STRING at [2:34]`. Pretty weird, since `str` is definitely a variable of type STRING..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [@Timogavk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12472644/timogavk) for your answer, I spent a while looking for a solution.

Though in my case I had to change the DECLARE for something more like this, without the additional quotations for it to work (I was working on dynamically querying different tables):

```
DECLARE str STRING DEFAULT 'SELECT * FROM ' || <table_name> || ' Limit 10';
```